# MySQL Error - InnoDB Doesn't Work And Server Instantly Shutdown

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, fixed

i'm trying to set up a MySQL server with XAMPP, it's not working and i'm getting this error:

```
2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

2014-10-28 14:14:38 588 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This 
option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] InnoDB: C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Extracted From mysql.log

I did try reinstalling, using AppleWS, and some fixes that i found here. None of them worked.

Answer (score 5):

These lines:

```
2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] InnoDB: C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode

2014-10-28 14:14:38 3768 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
```

.. indicate a problem with permissions.

Check the permissions on C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 and ensure that whatever user you're running your server under has read/write access to that folder.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem following the following steps:

1. I moved all files and directories from `C:\xampp\mysql\data\` to another directory.
2. I started MySQL from XAMPP to generate new files.
3. I moved not generated files and directories to `C:\xampp\mysql\data\`.

This method didn't make me lost my configuration and my databases

Answer (score -2):

Just delete `ibdata1` and `iblog` files in `C:\xampp\mysql\data\` folder.

Comment: This is actually a very dangerous suggestion as the ibdata1 file is a very important one and you should never delete it unless  you want to drop all your InnoDB data. Even if you used innodb_file_per_table=1 the ibdata1 file still contains the data dictionary, which tells MySQL useful information about your InnoDB tablespace. Before issuing such a critical action like deleting ibdata1, make sure to backup all of you databases and important data: you will have to restore everything after that!